# TV movie about a man scared of a figure seen in mirrors

Tags: story-identification, tv, horror

There's a short TV movie I remember seeing as a kid that I thought was really scary and have never found out what it was. Can anyone help naming it?

I remember seeing this on television approx 15-20 years ago in the UK, but I'm sure it was an American made. It was about a man who discovered that whenever he saw a reflection of himself (e.g. on bottles, glass, windows), a small black figure was behind him. When he turned around nothing was there. At first he thought it was funny but as it got closer and closer he became more frightened and avoided looking at anything reflective. At the end it got too unbearable and he stood in a mirror and let it come for him.

Some part of me believes it may have a link to Steven Spielberg but this may be a red herring? Also I'm almost certain this was not an Outer Limits or Twighlight Zone episode but a standalone program as I've seen almost all episodes of both.

Comment: They both sound like Twilight Zone or Outer Limits stories, but I don't recognize either off hand.

Answer (score 20):

Is it perhaps "[Mirror, Mirror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror,_Mirror_%28Amazing_Stories_episode%29)" of the Amazing Stories TV series?

> The plot is centered around Jordan Manmoth (Sam Waterston), a author of horror novels. One day, following an appearance on The Dick Cavett Show, he mistreats a young fan awaiting his idol at his doorstep, and soon thereafter begins to see a phantom-like character approaching him whenever he looks in the mirror or any reflective surface. Nobody else can see the monster, even when they look into the same mirror at the same time as Jordan. At the end of the episode, Jordan inadvertently sees his reflection in his girlfriend Karen's (Helen Shaver) eye; at this point, the phantom in the reflection grabs him from behind and begins to strangle him. To Karen, it seems that Jordan is strangling himself, but then Jordan turns into the phantom in the physical world. Discovering what he has become, Jordan throws himself from the upper-story bedroom window, leaving Karen horror-stricken.

Answer (score 1):

There was a Kiefer Southerland movie in 2008 called "Mirrors" which sounds similar. I saw it and it wasn't bad. You might be able to find it on Netflix. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0790686/

Comment: Not a match, although it's also not a bad movie in my opinion. He seldom saw figures behind him in the mirror and they weren't gradually getting closer when he did.

Answer (score 0):

*[Mirror, Mirror](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0511104/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl)* from *Amazing Stories* in 1986.  You can watch on NBC, a lot of commercials but it's free.

> An egotistical horror novelist dismisses the supernatural in real life, but he is forced to reconsider his disbelief when he finds himself pursued by a bizarre figure with a misshapen face. The strange thing? He can only see the man when he looks in the mirror. Each time he looks into a reflective surface, he finds the weird figure gaining on him with malicious intent, which has him terrified of what will happen if the ghastly figure should ever reach him.

[NBC online streaming of the film](https://www.nbc.com/amazing-stories/video/mirror-mirror/2909110)