# Looking for a horror story about a man pursued by a reflection in the mirror

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a story which I read approximately in the late nineties/early 00s. I read it in German. It might have been a short story from a book containing other similar short stories, but I am not sure about that. The author might have been Stephen King, but I am not sure about that either.

I don't remember many details, but the main character was definitely male, and he was seeing a figure slowly approaching him in any reflecting surface, but whenever he turned around, there was nothing there.

He was terrified about what would happen when the figure in the mirror finally reached him, so he hid away somewhere without a reflecting surface, just barely before the figure caught him.

It ends with

> the protagonist looking into the eyes of someone - most likely a love interest, but I don't know for sure - only to find that the eyes show his reflection. The figure finally reaches him and strangles him, and I believe that he dies.

The setting, as far as I can remember, was the normal world at the (then-)current time.

I think that the book I read was not brand new, and given the age of similar books I read at that time I would think that it has been published not earlier than the 80s.

Based on the [Wikipedia Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Reaper%27s_Image), it does not seem to be "The Reaper's image" by Stephen King.

In the spirit of providing as much detail as possible, for some reason I remember that another story of the book contained a vicious cat, but I might be confusing this with another book I read at that time. That other story is most likely "The Cat from Hell" by Stephen King, as it matches a few of the details I remember from that story.

Comment: While looking for anthologies containing The Cat from Hell I found [this anthology in German](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?676380). Could this have been the book you are thinking of?

Comment: Possibly related, although it's about a show and not a written story: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/tv-movie-about-a-man-scared-of-a-figure-seen-in-mirrors

Comment: @JohnRennie, I reviewed the story in that anthology, but I couldn't find the story I am looking for. Thanks though!

Comment: @Raj That's an odd case - I have viewed the trailer and have never seen this before. However, the story definitely matches what I have read! I am currently trying to find a novelization of this story

Comment: @PhilippFlenker It is odd - I'm not able to find any indication that the show/ movie was based on the short story. but the premise and the ending both seem to match exactly.

Comment: Me neither! I was wondering if the story was published as part of a book for the German market, but so far, I could not find anything.

Comment: Apparently the German name of the show was "Unglaubliche Geschichten". To add to the confusion, there IS a book series  of short stories called "Unglaubliche Geschichten" which I definitely read in the 90s, but it seems to be completely unrelated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105404/discussion-between-raj-and-philipp-flenker).

Comment: There is a short story called [Mirror, Mirror](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?677809) in [Steven Spielberg's Amazing Stories vol II](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?211413), which I think may be a tied to the TV show in the question Raj mentioned. Could this be it? I cannot find a copy anywhere - even archive.org has let me down this time.

Comment: Yes, that's it. "Steven Spielberg's neue unglaubliche Geschichten" in German, hence my connection to Stephen King. Thanks for all the efforts, Raj and John,  I would be happy to accept an answer, so that you get the rep you deserve :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OP [confirmed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/228414/looking-for-a-horror-story-about-a-man-pursued-by-a-reflection-in-the-mirror?noredirect=1#comment626077_228414) that the story is [Mirror, Mirror](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?677809) from [Volume II of Steven Spielberg's Amazing Stories](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?211413). While I haven't read it myself, it seems that it was adapted from the [Amazing Stories](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0511104/) TV series. The episode has this plot description on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazing_Stories_(1985_TV_series)):

> A horror novelist is haunted by a figure in his mirror.

The show was (probably) [the answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5743/106383) to another question on this site.

Thanks to [John Rennie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/228414/looking-for-a-horror-story-about-a-man-pursued-by-a-reflection-in-the-mirror?noredirect=1#comment626076_228414), for finding this.

Comment: Aw man... I saw the TV show when searching, but didn't see it was based on a short story.

Comment: I think it was the other way round: Steven Bauer created the book based on the TV series!

Comment: @PhilippFlenker if we've (finally! :-) identified the book please click on the green tick mark to the left of Raj's answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Done! Thanks again!